# YouTrack 5.1 Mailbox integration - Reply to mail

Tags: youtrack

When I try to reply to an e-mail the lay-out of my comment is always buggy.

1. When I reply in gmail I don't see the comment
2. When I reply in outlook I see my e-mail as a comment but the orignal mail is posted in the comment too.

Are there other people having these issues and can I fix them somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> When I reply in gmail I don't see the comment

It must be the [the following issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-23718), claimed to be fixed in 5.1.1. There's also a workaround described: add several linebreaks after message body and YouTrack should be able to parse it.

> When I reply in outlook I see my e-mail as a comment but the orignal mail is posted in the comment too.

They also have a [ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-24221) for that, so you can try voting for it. Sometimes it helps to speed up the fix.